# Как анимировать строку поиска?

Tags: java, android

Есть `Activity` содержащий `Edit text` который находится посередине экрана .Как сделать чтобы при введение текста в `Edit text` он подняся наверх прям под `ActionBar`

Comment: Я правильно понял, юзер нажимает на поле ввода, пишет одну букву и внезапно это поле перескакивает наверх?

Comment: да имеено так )как бы можно реальзоать

Comment: А на экране есть что то кроме текстового поля? Желательно прикрепить скрин, или хотя бы схему экрана, как он выглядит до того, как поле ввода оказалось наверху и после. Если мои предположения оправдаются, то для твоего случая есть очень простой способ

Comment: я уже сделал добавил анимацию

Comment: но спасибо , попой же в ответе покажу решение

Comment: и скрины, на случай, если мое решение все-таки проще

Comment: Экран пустой только эдит текст ,заинтриговали хотелосьбы узнать ваше решение

Comment: Просто сместился наверх окна или в Toolbar прям? Плавно сместился или можно чтоб перепрыгнул? Мне что-то подсказывает, что вы хотите чтоб просто клава не перекрывала его, это вам надо?

Comment: именно так и надо

Comment: чтоб не перекрыала